# Angular2: get the count of child components - when in the lifecycle and how

Tags: javascript, angular

So, for illustration purposes lets say I have two components

- tabset

  - tabitem

where tabset is the parent that has many tabitems

- tabset

  - tabitem1
  - tabitem2
  - tabitem3
  - etc...

So, depending on how many tabitems there are inside tabset I will calculate some stuff...

so, how do I get the item count?

(the item count should be accessible in the child component)...

so I have reference of the parent like this

```
<tabset #tabset>
    <tabitem [tabset]="tabset">....</tabitem>
    <tabitem [tabset]="tabset">....</tabitem>
    <tabitem [tabset]="tabset">....</tabitem>
</tabset>
```

So how do I go from here?
When in the life-cycle of tabset I will know how many elements there are actually in? and do I need to use vanilla javascript with *ElementRef* and *getElementsByTagName* ? Or is there any other, more angular friendly way?

One extra question.... how can I pass the component's reference via **ng-content**?

**tabset.html**

```
<div class="...." #tabset>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
```

Comment: You could use `@ContentChildren(TabItem) items: QueryList<TabItem>;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@ContentChildren(TabItem) tabItems: QueryList<TabItem>;

ngAfterContentInit() {
  console.log(this.tabItems.length);
}
```

Note: `TabItem` can be a component too, not only a directive

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the quick response... Gunter I told you, you should be epmloyed by the NG2 team! AWESOME!  Any thoughts on the second question? I would like to pass the number of tabItems to the tabitem component... without setting the [tabset]="tabset" on every tabitem

Comment: You can use `this.tabItems.forEach((ti) => ti.count = tabItems.toArray().length)`. You can subscribe to changes of `this.tabItems()` so you know when you need to update the value in the`TabItem` components.

Comment: How do I get the HTML element from tabItem? (from ti <- inside of the forEach loop)?

Comment: `@ContentChildren(TabItem, {read: ElementRef}) tabItems:QueryList<TabItem>;`. Then you can reference the element with `this.tabItems.toArray[0].nativeElement;`

Comment: so I need to have another array... one to access angular component's property, and the other one to access the ElementRef?

Comment: your code should probably read: @ContentChildren(TabItem, {read: ElementRef}) tabItems:QueryList<ElementRef>;  ;)

Comment: @Gunter From where I can get "TabItem", Could you please explain?
How and where I should define "TabItem" ?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma `TabItem` is the class of a custom component. You have to create it yourself.