# How to loop/count components in an angular2 app?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Basically the title says all. How would I loop through all of my components or just get the number of them in my project. Let's say I have 15 components in my **angular2** application. How to display this number? Without including them in the main *app.components.html*?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023068/angular2-get-the-count-of-child-components-when-in-the-lifecycle-and-how

Comment: You can manually display the count. just increase the count while you create a new component.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script that goes through your project and looks for components.

**for windows:**
open a command prompt, navigate to `yourproject/src`, the following commant will return the amount of components:

```
dir /s | find /c "component.ts"
```

You can add `>file.txt` to the end to save this number a file.

Now you can read from this file from your application and display the number.

-

You can also leave out the `/c` for a list of all the components